# PHP Mysql: select where array_intersect

Tags: php, mysql

I need to find out those employees whose accepted working locations contain ANY of the target cities of our next construction project. That is, if there is any intersection between the target location array and the employee's desired location array, it will be OK.

Can I query like this?

```
SELECT * 
  FROM employee-list
 WHERE array_intersect ($target-cities, accepted-locations) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: what is the structure of accepted-locations? Do you have a target-cities table? That will determine your answer

Comment: The SQL solution will require 3 tables to be efficient:
employee_list, accepted_locations and target_cities. With that structure, I can give you the proper SQL statement

Comment: Well, what happens when you try it?

Comment: Jacques, the location array has a straight forword structure like [new york, london, vancouver ....]. All are city names. No complication of state or province or country. Similar is the query field array. There is no table. I assume that all spellings are careful and correct.

Comment: miken32, I cannot test it now as i am a starter, just learning the basics now. Not yet set up the test server. I searched for this kind of query but found no one writing such kind of query online. So i asked this question to check if the syntax is correct. This will be a necessary search condition for my planned poject.

Comment: Jacques, I understand that without a standardized location table it will be less efficient. But now my primary concern is whether this query syntax and logic is correct.      I will try to figure out how to improve efficiency and precision later.

Comment: pls show table schema

Comment: Jacques, target cities will be hand input on the search form. It is an array depending on each construction project, which spans several cities each time.   While accepted locations are just a field in the employee list table, being an array of strings.

Comment: Table has 2 colomns: employee name, accepted-locations.      The latter being a simple array like ['new york', 'beijing', 'london'].      When I have a construction project happening in [New york, london] at the same time, I want to search out those emploees who can accept ANY of these locations.